# React Redux -> How can I use UUID to give unique IDs to my products and then use that ID to remove them from the cart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a hobby project as a part of learning react by making an "e-commerce" like website. So I got to the part where I am adding the products in the cart but I hit a brick wall. I can't figure out how to index them and then remove them. I've tried creating different variables to store their ID but it didn't really work since the default value was 0 and everytime I pressed the add button they all had the same ID of 1 because that was what I was increasing the 0 by. Anyway I also tried to store that variable in a state but it didn't work out as well. The most recent thing i've tried is using UUID but I am not sure how can I send the ID to the reducer and compare it with, well here's where I get lost. How would I compare the product's ID, more like-> What would I compare it with? I'm planning on creating a variable called indexOfProduct and then that variable would basically be my redux-storage with the ID of the product which I want to remove, once the ID is found I'll just create a new instance of the storage without it. How can I do that? I am posting the code before I tried the UUID approach
Here are my files:

reducers.js

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
const reducer = (state={productsInCart:[{}]}, action)=>
{
    let nextId = 0;
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'addToCart':
            return{
                
                ...state,
                productsInCart: [...state.productsInCart, {name: action.name, price: action.price, image: action.image, id: action.id}]            
            }
            
        case 'clearCart':
            return{
                ...state,
                productsInCart: []   
            }
        case 'removeProduct':
            return{

                ...state, 
                productsInCart:[state.productsInCart.filter(product=>product.id!==action.id)]}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

cart.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button, Nav, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavItem, NavLink} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {MdHome} from 'react-icons/md'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from './store'
class cart extends Component {
    render() {
        const {productsInCart} = this.props;
        const clearCart=()=>
        {
            store.dispatch({type: 'clearCart'})
        }
        const removeProduct=()=>
        {
           store.dispatch({type:'removeProduct'})
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar variant='dark' bg='success'>
                    <NavbarBrand>Your cart</NavbarBrand>
                    <Nav className='ml-auto'>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href='/home'>
                                <MdHome size={25}></MdHome>
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                {productsInCart.map(product=>
                <div className='productsList'>
                    <div className='productShow'>
                    <h3 className='productName'>{product.name}</h3>
                    <img className='productImage'src={product.image}></img>
                    <p className='productPrice'><strong>$ {product.price}.00</strong></p>
                    <Button variant='danger'><strong onClick={()=>removeProduct(product)}>Remove product</strong></Button>
                    </div>

                </div>)}
                <Button onClick={()=>clearCart()}>Clear Cart</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}
const mapStateToProps=(state={productsInCart: [{}]})=>
{
    return{
        productsInCart: state.productsInCart
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(cart);
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from './store'
import {Button, Nav, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavItem, NavLink} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {MdShoppingBasket, MdAddShoppingCart} from 'react-icons/md'
import './index.css'
class index extends Component {
    render() {
        let idCounter=0;
        
        const {productsInCart} = this.props;
        const productsList = [
            {
                name: 'Cool Hat',
                price: 50, 
                image: '/Hat.png',
            },
            {
                name: 'Dull Hat',
                price: 5, 
                image: '/Hat.png',
            },]
        const addWord=(product)=>
        {
            idCounter+=1
            store.dispatch({type: 'addToCart', name: product.name, price: product.price, image: product.image, id: idCounter})
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className ='navbar' variant='light'>
                    <NavbarBrand>Home</NavbarBrand>
                    <Nav className='ml-auto'>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href='/cart'>
                                <span className='cartIndicator'><MdShoppingBasket size={25}></MdShoppingBasket>
                                <span>{productsInCart.length}</span></span>
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                {productsList.map(product=>
                <div className='productsList'>
                    <div className='productShow'>
                    <h3 className='productName'>{product.name}</h3>
                    <img className='productImage'src={product.image}></img>
                    <p className='productPrice'><strong>$ {product.price}.00</strong></p>
                    <Button className='addProductButton' variant='success' onClick={()=>addWord(product)}> <MdAddShoppingCart size={20}></MdAddShoppingCart> <strong>Add to cart </strong> </Button>

                    </div>
                </div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state={productsInCart: [{}]})=>
{
    return{
        productsInCart: state.productsInCart
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(index);
```

Comment: pass Id as parametr of action, just make UUID,v4().toString() and then you have uniq id in reducer. or just create id in reducer during createing new product. learn (https://github.com/immerjs/immer) it will help you manipulating store state

Comment: That's one of the options I am considering but here's the thing with it, correct me if I am wrong but what happens is I set the unique ID or I pass it as a parameter in action and then I have to use it to find the index of a certain product. That would most likely be done by using indexOf but I've got to compare it with something if so. What would I compare the unique ID with?

Comment: id is a string so just like other strings ?

Answer (score 1):

You should install the `react-uuid` and import it, following that use it when you add item throughout your add reducer like so:

```js
import uuid from "react-uuid";
 .
 .
 . 
 const addWord=(product)=>
        {
            store.dispatch({type: 'addToCart', name: product.name, price: product.price, image: product.image, id: uuid()})
        }
```

Then you can give the id to your remove reducer:

```js
 {productsInCart.map(product=>
               .
               .
               .
               <Button variant='danger'><strong onClick={()=>removeProduct(product.id)}>Remove product</strong></Button>
               .
               .
               .
```